# Struts2 tiles issue

Tags: struts2, tiles

I have a tiles definition like

```
<definition name="tasks" template="/jsp/layout/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/jsp/layout/header.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="nav" value="/jsp/layout/navigation.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/jsp/task/menu.jsp#ShowUser" />
</definition>
```

I want to add a anchor in the value for an attribute and this anchor needs to be set based on the attribute set the controller.
 For eg

```
<put-attribute name="menu" value="/jsp/task/menu.jsp#ShowUser" />
```

However this does not seem to work.

Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: Can you see your question, and how not formatting caused something rather important to not appear?

Comment: For eg what ? Plz complete your question

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this (there may be another way?) would be to combine the use of OGNL in your action result location and a wild card in your Tile definition.

Suppose I have this action:

```
public class DynamicTileAction {

   MyModel model

   public String execute() { 
      return "success"; 
   }

   public MyModel getModel() { 
      return this.model; 
   }

   //other code...

}
```

And this result definition:

```
<result name="success" type="tiles">dynamic.tile.${model.someField}</result>
```

Then in the tiles.xml I can do this:

```
<definition name="dynamic.tile.*">
    <put-attribute name="dynamicField" value="{1}" />
</definition>
```

or, you can use it to dynamically include a JSP:

```
<definition name="dynamic.tile.*">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/content/dynamic/{1}.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Then, each place that you see `{1}` above will equal the value of `getModel().getSomeField()`.

Comment: I want to add a anchor in the tiles definition to redirect the control to a tab in my jsp file. Any idea how this can be done, the tiles does not seem to accept # in the attribute value.<put-attribute name="menu" value="/jsp/task/menu.jsp#ShowUser" />